# In the 1980s Garfield Cartoon show and classic comic strips, can Jon literally "understand" Garfield?

Tags: cartoon, telepathy, garfield-the-cat

In the old Garfield cartoons and strips, we [the audience] "hear" and "see" Garfield's thoughts and communications clearly, even though he doesn't move his mouth. This, combined with other animals "speaking" to each other in a similar fashion gives the impression of a type of "telepathic communication" as the norm. However, often Jon seems to indicate that he *does* understand what Garfield is thinking of, especially when the cat specifically refers to a given context, the situation they are currently dealing with, or food.

This runs somewhat contrary to other examples in the show; Garfield has been shown "speaking" directly to an audience and then asking him questions which he answers. also, the animals on Orsan's Farm/U.S. Acres all communicate with each other, *but* in their cases **their mouths move.** In the *New Garfield* show, we see Garfield's mouth move as well, but it's never shown that he and Jon "speak" directly, as in having a conversation; it more comes across as Jon interpreting Garfield's behavior as a type of sign language.

So does Jon "hear" Garfield's thoughts, then?

Comment: I've answered this, but the answer confirms that the property in question is neither science fictional, nor fantastical, and hence off-topic. I would suggest we migrate it to movies:SE for the cartoon and/or Lit:SE for the comic strip

Comment: Apologies; i thought this counted as it is a comic and cartoon. Still, thank you.

Comment: It certainly has elements of fantasy about it (cats don't typically drink coffee or have opposable thumbs) but the fact that it's unremarkable *in-universe* means that it's not treated as fantasy by us.

Comment: I'm no Garfield expert, but my daughter watches the shows and there are definitely episodes which have fantastical/sci-fi elements. Just from the few episodes I've seen there's at least one recurring alien character and an episode where a UFO crashes in their yard, and there's another episode where first Odie, then Garfield, are transformed into were-beasts by some unusual planetary alignment. I don't recall these being "dream" episodes so I have to assume aliens and were-beasts are canon in at least the TV show.

Comment: [Related](https://garfieldminusgarfield.net/)

Comment: Oddly, I've never noticed _any_ character in _any_ comic strip moving his/her mouth...

Comment: @FreeMan So when lip positions of characters change while they are talking....that doesn't count as moving their lips?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the strip's creator, Jon doesn't understand Garfield, but he does ***understand his actions***.

> **Jim:** *I wanted to ride that real fine line between wanting to understand what the cat says, I think people honestly feel that cats think in English, that cats understand everything as they do but obviously they don't talk so I wanted to ride that line between here's what your cat is really thinking to give pet owners insight into what their pets are really thinking without giving it away, to have him really talk and Jon understand him, would have made it more of a fantasy. I always wanted to create a strip that could have cats, if they had opposable thumbs, would drink coffee if they could. Apparently Heathcliff, a cat in a comic strip panel, would fly planes and drive cars and be on a desert island and I didn't want to do that. I wanted to create a very real world and then go out to the fantasy from there. And, **you'll notice that when Jon understands what Garfield is saying, it's something Garfield does with an action, not a word that communicates it.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Garfield: An Interview with Jim Davis](https://www.blackfilm.com/20040611/features/jimdavis.shtml)</sup></sub>

Comment: To add to your comment, I remember a strip (but not the album it was in) where Jon asks a question, Garfield answers, and then Jon says "I wish you could understand what I'm saying". Garfield then moves its arms to show he understands Jon, with no success. I'll try to find it.

Comment: Before "Garfield Minus Garfield", there was a similar strip in which all of Garfield's thought bubbles were deleted. The creator had read Jim Davis's confirmation that Jon couldn't understand him, and decided to effectively remix the strip to show; this is about a lonely guy who talks to his pets and has almost no human contact.

Comment: @valorum But dude, we _see_ Garfield doing all these human things [drinking coffee, changing the TV channel, even having opposable thumbs] in the strip. And we **definitely** see all of that in the cartoons. So is Jim Davis contradicting himself, or is there some other explanation?

Comment: @RussRainford - authors of long-term works like comic strips and books often contradict themselves out of sheer boredom or just plain forgetting what the rules are, of the world they created

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica I'd never heard of Garfield Minus Garfield before. Depressing yet insightful stuff!

Comment: @RussRainford "I always wanted to create a strip that could have cats, if they had opposable thumbs, would drink coffee if they could." That doesn't seem contradictory at all. He doesn't want cats who talk and fly planes; he just wants cats who understand English and use opposable thumbs.